# Associating Android phone to Telegram web, where is Devices section in the Telegram app?

Tags: telegram

I am trying to associate the web version of Telegram, https://web.telegram.org/, with my phone. The instructions say to scan the QR code with three-lines menu in the Telegram app on the phone, and there Settings/Devices.

But under three-lines/Settings there is no item Devices.

Where do I find it? Any other way, such as eg. scanning the code  from another app, not from within the Telegram app if I can't find Devices there?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, found it: three-lines menu (top left) / Settings / Privacy  and Security / Devices at the bottom of the top part of the list list. (5thitem from top.)